# Blog automatically redirected to error page

Tags: errors, 404-error, blog

I have a blog [link](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/). It was loading fine, but now when I open it. It redirects to error page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a meta tag in your body, causing refresh:

```
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=error.htm">
```

Comment: not its not there.

Comment: yes it is - see line 328: http://pastebin.com/FB5BqgBC

Comment: Oh I see. It was my solution post. Great.